# How to makle a video link appear within a HTML code on Arduino w/Ethernet Shield?

Tags: html, arduino

I'm pretty much a novice in arduino code and I'm having trouble with the following code. When I compile it with arduino 0022 there are no errors. If I access the Ethernet shield I see the HTML page fine. The troubles come with that the link to the video I want to post in the code. I'm able to see the frame but the link doesn't ever come up. within that frame all I see is the HTML page that has been created. Is there a chance that there's an error in the code or HTML formatting? Is there a specific Library I need to use? thanks in advance for the help!

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Client.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <Server.h>
#include <Udp.h>
#include <Servo.h>
char Link[]= "http://www.anywebsite.com"; //video link
Servo tilt;
Servo pan;
int panpos = 90;
int tiltpos = 90;
byte mac[] = { 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC, 0xDD, 0xEE, 0xFF }; //physical mac address
byte ip[] = { 192, 128, 13, 169 };           // ip in lan
byte gateway[] = {  192, 128, 13,1 };            // internet access via router
byte subnet[] = { 255, 255, 255, 0 };                   //subnet mask
Server server(80);                                      //server port
String readString = String(30); //string for fetching data from address
void setup(){
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, gateway, subnet);
  Serial.begin(9600);
 tilt.attach(3);
pan.attach(9);
  tilt.write(90);
  pan.write(90);
}
void loop(){
// Create a client connection
Client client = server.available();
  if (client) {
    while (client.connected()) {
   if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
     //read char by char HTTP request
    if (readString.length() < 100)
      {
        //store characters to string
        readString += c;
      }
        Serial.print(c);
        if (c == '\n') {
          if (readString.indexOf("?") <0)
          {
            //do nothing
          }
          else
          {           
             if(readString.indexOf("UP=UP") >0)
               {
                 movetiltupstep();
               }
            else if(readString.indexOf("DN=DN") >0)
               {
                 movetiltdownstep();
               }
             else if(readString.indexOf("LT=LT") >0)
               {
                 movepanleftstep();
               }
             else if(readString.indexOf("RT=RT") >0)
               {
                 movepanrightstep();
               }
             else if(readString.indexOf("CN=CN") >0)
           {
             center();
           }
      }
      // now output HTML data starting with standard header
      client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
      client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
      client.println();
      //set background to green
      client.print("<body style=background-color:blue>");
      client.println("<hr />");
      client.println("<center>");
      client.println("<h1>Camera control</h1>");
      client.println("<form method=get name=SERVO>");
      client.println("<input type=submit value=UP name=UP style=\"width:100px\"><br>");
      client.println("<input type=submit value=LT name=LT style=\"width:100px\"><input type=submit value=CN name=CN style=\"width:100px\"><input type=submit value=RT name=RT style=\"width:100px\"><br>");
      client.println("<input type=submit value=DN name=DN style=\"width:100px\">");
      client.println("<hr />");
      client.println("<iframe width= 640 height= 360  src= Link[]frameborder= 0  allowfullscreen></iframe>");
      client.println("</form>");
      client.println("</center>");
      client.println("</body></html>");
      //clearing string for next read
      readString="";
      //stopping client
      client.stop();
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
void movetiltupstep(){
  tiltpos = tilt.read();
  Serial.println(tiltpos);
  if (tiltpos >= 66)
  {
  tilt.write(tiltpos - 2);
  }
}
void movetiltdownstep(){
  tiltpos = tilt.read();
  Serial.println(tiltpos);
  if (tiltpos <= 116)
  {
  tilt.write(tiltpos + 2);
  }
}
void movepanleftstep(){
  panpos = pan.read();
  Serial.println(panpos);
  if (panpos >= 4)
  {
  pan.write(panpos - 4);
  }
}
void movepanrightstep(){
  panpos = pan.read();
  Serial.println(panpos);
  if (panpos <= 176)
  {
  pan.write(panpos + 4);
  }
}
void center(){
  panpos = pan.read();
  tiltpos = tilt.read();
  Serial.println(panpos);
  if (panpos < 90)
  {
   for(int i = panpos; i <= 90; i++) {
      pan.write(i);
    }
  }
  else if (panpos > 90)
  {
    for(int i = panpos; i >= 90; i--) {
      pan.write(i);
}
  }
  if (tiltpos < 90)
  {
    for(int i = tiltpos; i <= 90; i++) {
      tilt.write(i);
    }
  }
  else if (tiltpos > 90)
  {
    for(int i = tiltpos; i >= 90; i--) {
      tilt.write(i);
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, actually, your code cannot work. Let's put appart the wrong formatting of the line ("Link[]" which is concatenated to "frameborder"), the page that should start with <html>, that you are lucky to be in a very specific case where the Content-Length header is not required and so on, and let's focus on what you tried to do.

You tried to do what is called a variable interpolation: you assumed that the variable name "Link[]" in the string will be replaced by another string. It is something that does not exist in C or C++.

There are several way to do what you want (you can take a look at the String class which exists since Arduino-019 http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject and what is called concatenation http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringConcat).

In your case, you can simply do that (not tested, but should explain the trick):

```
client.print("<iframe width=640 height=360 src=");
client.print(Link); // Link is not between quotes!
client.println(" frameborder=0 allowfullscreen></iframe>");
```

It is less beautiful than what you wanted to do, but it is enough for what you need.

Comment: I works like a charm. The only thing I did was instead of: client.print on those two lines I put: client.println... Thanks for the help Vincent!

Comment: In your case it is still valid. Instead of concatenating characters, the use of println() in place of print() will force the addition of new lines between each "print". In that case the standard of HTML is flexible enough, the HTML "source code" will just look a bit weird.